# Why did Julia devs rename `NA` to `missing`

Tags: julia

This might seem like a silly trivial question but I am genuinely curious why the Julia devs decided to change the naming for missing values. Seeing as Julia is designed to be very similar to existing languages and pipelines based on R and Python, I don't quite get why they would introduce a long and clumsy name for NAs which would be intuitive to anyone coming from MATLAB/R.

Comment: I've been using Matlab for over 20 years, and had no idea that `NA` should be intuitive to me. `Missing`, on the other hand, is _very_ intuitive.

Comment: Also, think of all the second-language English speakers. Acronyms are always more obscure. (As a side note: even worse is the usage of a slash for abreviations, as in N/A.)

Comment: I wouldn't say that Julia is designed to be similar to R or Python (meaning that it is not intended to be similar to them), but of course the development have been inspired by other languages (including Python and R, among others).

Comment: [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The supposition that `NA` is standard in other languages is actually not true:

- R, [yes](https://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html) — the only one that uses `NA`
- Matlab, [no](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/missing.html) — `NaN`, `NaT`, `missing`, others
- Python, [no](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.04-missing-values.html) — `NaN`, `None`, others
- SQL, [no](https://swcarpentry.github.io/sql-novice-survey/05-null/) — `NULL`

There's almost no consistency across languages. Except for one thing: they all use the term "missing data" when explaining it. When someone sees `NA` for the first time, they have no idea what it might mean. Even when you know, it's unclear what it stands for. Does it mean "Not assigned"? "Not available"? "Not applicable"? "No answer"? These are all quite different concepts, which leads to confusion and misuse. Since "missing" is the word that is consistently used to describe what `NA` is meant to be used for, why not call it that? Using the name `missing` also clears up confusion about meaning: `missing` unambiguously represents a missing value.